# Xcode Command-Line tool can't find pathForResource

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, command-line-tool

I'm making an application that will take JSON and turn it into CoreData, basically copying: 
 [THIS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated)

My problem is that I  think a change in Xcode has made it so that Command Line doesn't use NSBundle, and so using pathForResource always returns nil, and so I can't access my files in the Copy files part of Build Phases.

Does anyone know how to access these files in a Command Line tool?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Sam

PS. I've tried  [this solution](http://www.bricewilson.net/blog/2013/01/11/command-line-tool-resources/)  to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Use that:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"filetype"];
```

Instead of mainBundle. It works for UnitTests as well as standard builds. "MainBundle" is only for phone builds.